# SQL query initial and final balance as well sum of events

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a fairly big table (about 300gb) as:

```
event_day event_hour customer_id initial_bal final_bal topups debts
01/01     00         11111       0           50        60     10
01/01     01         11111       50          80        45     15
01/01     02         11111       80          30        0      50
...
```

I want to summarize it into whole days, e.g.:

```
event_day customer_id initial_bal final_bal topups debts
01/01     11111       0           30        105    75
...
```

But I´m having troubles with the analitical functions.. I'm working with something like:

```
select *
from
(
  select
    event_day, customer_id, initial_bal, final_bal,
    sum(topups) over (partition by event_day, customer_id by event_day, customer_id asc) topups,
    row_number() over (partition by event_day, customer_id order by event_day, customer_id asc) as initial_bal,
    row_number() over (partition by event_day, customer_id order by event_day, customer_id desc) as final_bal
  from MY_300GB_TABLE t
)
where initial_bal = 1 or final_bal = 1
order by customer_id, event_day
```

Which inst doing what I expected... a hand?

I´m tring to avoid joins, sub-queries and such.. I simplified here but there the actual project involves a few big tables and performance might an issue. I'm using Oracle 12C.

thanks!

Comment: The columns in your query doesn't match with the table you posted. what's `dia` and `cli_id`? Also, what's the datatype of `event_day`? If it's a string, what does `01/01` represent?

Comment: For the daily opening and closing balances, you need to partition by customerid and day, order by hour - ordering asc for the initial balance, and desc for the final balance - and then you need to group by customerid and day to consolidate the two rows that will exist for each customer and day. The total debits and credits need to be executed in a separate query from the balance query above, by simply summing those columns whilst grouping by customerid and day, and then joining these two separate queries.

Comment: @KaushikNayak, fixed the mistakes, thanks. event_day is a date field and "01/01" is  just my john doe of dates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good occasion to aggregate with [first](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) (or `last`) option:

```
select event_day, customer_id,
       max(initial_bal) keep (dense_rank first order by event_hour) initial_bal,
       max(final_bal) keep (dense_rank last order by event_hour) final_bal,
       sum(topups) topups, sum(debts) debts
  from tla_t_balance_summary t
  group by event_day, customer_id;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a73b7386b72696da260656182d829b22)</sup>**

Your query works too, but you made a mistake in `order by`. And it requires additional aggregation, because we have two rows for customers:

```
select event_day, customer_id, max(topups), max(debts),
       min(case rib when 1 then initial_bal end) ib, min(case rfb when 1 then final_bal end) fb 
  from (
    select event_day, customer_id, initial_bal, final_bal,
           sum(topups) over (partition by event_day, customer_id) topups,
           sum(debts) over (partition by event_day, customer_id) debts,
           row_number() over (partition by event_day, customer_id order by event_hour) as rib,
           row_number() over (partition by event_day, customer_id order by event_hour desc) as rfb
      from tla_t_balance_summary t)
  where rib = 1 or rfb = 1
  group by customer_id, event_day;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the first and last entry for each day based on hour, your row_number function should reflect that, with something like:

```
select *
from
(
  select
    event_day, customer_id, initial_bal, final_bal,
    sum(recharge_amount) over (partition byevent_day, customer_id) topups,
    row_number() over (partition by event_day, customer_id order by event_hour asc) as initial_hr,
    row_number() over (partition by event_day, customer_id order by event_hour desc) as final_hr
  from TLA_T_BALANCE_SUMMARY t
)
where initial_hr = 1 or final_hr = 1
order by customer_id, event_day
```

Its hard to comment exactly because your query doesn't really match the data in terms of columns etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use `GROUP BY` and `analytical function` as following:

```
SELECT
    EVENT_DAY,
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    MAX(INITIAL_BAL) AS INITIAL_BAL,
    MAX(FINAL_BAL) AS FINAL_BAL,
    SUM(TOPUPS) AS TOPUPS,
    SUM(DEBTS) AS DEBTS
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            EVENT_DAY,
            CUSTOMER_ID,
            FIRST_VALUE(INITIAL_BAL) OVER(
                PARTITION BY EVENT_DAY, CUSTOMER_ID
                ORDER BY
                    EVENT_HOUR
            ) AS INITIAL_BAL,
            FIRST_VALUE(FINAL_BAL) OVER(
                PARTITION BY EVENT_DAY, CUSTOMER_ID
                ORDER BY
                    EVENT_HOUR DESC
            ) AS FINAL_BAL,
            TOPUPS,
            DEBTS
        FROM
            TLA_T_BALANCE_SUMMARY T
        WHERE
            INITIAL_BAL = 1
            OR FINAL_BAL = 1
    )
GROUP BY
    EVENT_DAY,
    CUSTOMER_ID
ORDER BY
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    EVENT_DAY;
```

Cheers!!